# If every $\kappa$-complete filter can be extended to a $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter, then some $\lambda\le\kappa$ is measurable

Tags: set-theory, filters, large-cardinals

I want to prove the following

We have $\kappa$ an infinite regular cardinal such that every $\kappa$-complete filter on $\kappa$ can be extended to an $\omega_1$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$.

> Show that there exists a measurable cardinal $\lambda\leq\kappa$.

Moreover, if $\lambda$ is the least measurable cardinal less than or equal to $\kappa$, then in fact every $\kappa$-complete filter on $\kappa$ can be extended to a $\lambda$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$.

**Attempt** For the first part, I need to prove that there exist a $\lambda\leq \kappa$ such that there exist a $\lambda$-complete non-principal ultrafilter on $\lambda$. I'm stomped... I tried to the partition equivalence of a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter, trying to fit in some Ramsey theory and weakly compact cardinal, but i can't reach any conclusion. I also looked at strongly compact cardinal with no solution. I'm now trying a more constructive approach. Using the property of my cardinal to build a $\lambda$-complete non-principal ultrafilter on $\lambda$.

Maybe there are some equivalent definition of measurable that I could use here?
Any help is welcomed, thanks

Comment: (I fixed the title: you cannot prove that there is a measurable *strictly* below $\kappa$.)

Comment: Since you've got an $\omega_1$-complete nontrivial ultrafilter on $\kappa$, why don't you define $\lambda$ to be the smallest cardinal which carries an $\omega_1$-complete nontrivial ultrafilter? Then you've got $\lambda\le\kappa$ automatically, and you've got a nontrivial $\omega_1$-complete ultrafilter on $\lambda$. Maybe there's some way you can use minimality to show that the ultrafilter is $\lambda$-complete?

Comment: by nontrivial do you mean non-principal? If so I don't have a non-principal $\omega_1$ ultrafilter on $\kappa$. Is there any reason I can assume one extention will be non-trivial?

Comment: What if you extend the $\kappa$-complete filter $\{X\subseteq\kappa:|\kappa\setminus X|\lt\kappa$ to an $\omega_1$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$?

Comment: Indeed! I do know that any ultrafilter that extends the Fréchet filter is non-principal! Thanks, That should be a good point to start

Comment: @bof. That is exactly what to do. No need for Ramsey theory, etc. Just elementary  methods.